# Trouble with pointers to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

i am currently learning pointers and it looks like i can't handle them properly.
So i have an array of strings, which i represent like this:

```
char** array;
```

I can print all strings of the array with this function, it works fine:

```
void write_lines(char** array_of_string)
{
    for(; *array_of_string; array_of_string++)
        printf("%s", *array_of_string);
}
```

But what i want to do right now is to change the content of the array, to do so i want to use a function that takes a `char***` as a parameter:

```
void write_lines_2(char*** array_of_string)
{
    for(; ***array_of_string; (*array_of_string)++)
       printf("%s", **array_of_string);
}
```

This function is just a test, to see **how i can access the elements properly with a char*** as parameter**. And as you could expect it compile but crash when lauched.
**Could you explain me how to do it right?**
**Edit:** Eventually the function will swap strings in the array.
 
I already have a `swap(char** string, char** string2)` function, that is why i thought i needed a third pointer to change the content of the array passed as parameter and not only change a copy of it.
**Edit 2**: I tried a few more things and i realized that:

```
void write_lines(char*** array_of_string)
{
    int length = 3; // array goes from [0] to [3]

    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++) // It works!
        printf("%s", *(*array_of_string + i));

    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++, array_of_string++) // Crash
        printf("%s", **array_of_string);

    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++, array_of_string++); // Doesn't crash

    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++, (*array_of_string)++) // Crash
        printf("%s", **array_of_string);

    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++, (*array_of_string)++); // Crash
}
```

I guess i should be using `(*array_of_string)++` to change which string is pointed, because `array_of_string++` would change which array is pointed, but i am not sure. Anyway, even if i can build the function an other way, this is just an exercice so what matter for me is to understand why what i am trying to do doesn't work and i still dont know why.

Comment: You need to pass the size of the array.

Comment: You only need a pointer to the pointer to the pointer if you are going to change the pointer itself, which doesn't sound like your intent. You're saying you only want to change the *content* of the array, so your `char ** array_of_string` will suffice.

Comment: You don't show how are you calling the function. Present a minimal example please.

Comment: `for(; **array_of_string` is likely undefined behavior.  Post the calling code of `write_lines()`.

Comment: "...what i want to do right now is to change the content of the array...". What exactly do you want to change? The strings themselves? Or the location of the array in memory? Something else? If all you want to do is change the strings themselves, then there's no reason to use `char ***` parameter. Your original `char **` is already sufficient for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is slightly odd

```
void write_lines(char** array_of_string)
{
    for(; **array_of_string; array_of_string++)
        printf("%s", *array_of_string);
}
```

It says that the end of the array is an empty string. I think you really want

```
void write_lines(char** array_of_string)
{
    for(; *array_of_string; array_of_string++)
        printf("%s", *array_of_string);
}
```

It says that the end of the array is a null pointer. This is much more normal (for a start it allows empty lines in the array)

Comment: Indead i forgot to end my array of string with a pointer to null so checking for a character to be null worked while checking for the string to be null didnt. I fixed it and changed the **array_of_string to *array of string.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to terminate on a null character - it seems you want it to terminate on a `NULL` string. You'll want to make the following change:

```
void write_lines(char** array_of_string)
{
    // remove one dereference in the terminating condition of the loop
    for(; *array_of_string; array_of_string++)
        printf("%s", *array_of_string);
}
```

To make it more readable, I might write it the following way by passing the size of the array instead of worrying about `NULL` terminating the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2

// Note that I'm passing the char** and the size.
void write_lines(char** arr, size_t n) {
  if(!arr) return;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
   char* strings[SIZE] = { "Hello", "World" };
   write_lines(strings, SIZE);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain the downvote? I'm happy to learn from my mistakes, but I can't without feedback.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, by the OP code clearly shows that he uses a different method of passing the size. The size is passed implicitly, by creating a special "terminator" element at the end of the array - an empty string. If the array element is empty string, then it is the last element. If the OP want to use this convention and it works for him, he's free to do so. No need to pass the size explicitly in that case.

Comment: This isn't the problem. OP is terminating the array with an empty string.

Comment: @AnT Sure. Again, I don't know idiomatic C but it seems better to be explicit. Pointer hell is bad enough without guessing what's happening in the programmer's head.

Comment: @AnT My money is that OP's code "works" yet not because of the explicit terminator element, but because of UB.  Unless OP posts more, it is a guess.  OP does says "I can print all strings of the array".

Comment: Edited to explain OP's problem as he wrote it and offer my solution as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the frst function should look like this:

```
void write_lines(char** array_of_string)
{
    // char * = string (pointer to string start)
    // char ** = array of strings
    // the pointer to string start should be valid
    for(; *array_of_string; array_of_string++)
        printf("%s", *array_of_string);
}
```

Then, you can see, that when function argument becomes `char ***pointer_to_array_of_strings` then `char **array_of_strings = *pointer_to_array_of_strings`. And then you can act the same as in `write_lines`. The fault was in `(*pointer_to_array_of_string)++` as it will shift `array_of_strings` by `sizeof(char **)`.

P.S.: It is a little of mess here with `pointer_to_array_of_strings` and `array_of_strings`. Here I use former to indicate `char ***` and the latter to indicate `char **`.